# Check string on IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have an IEnumerable of this type of class ColumnInfo

```
namespace MyCompany
{
    public class ColumnInfo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }        
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
        public string ColumnName { get; set; }       
    }
}
```

In this class I have a ColumnName property that shows me string column names.

I have already a populated DataTable with some columns.

I need to remove columns from the data table that are not in my IEnumerable with property ColumnName. I need in my datatable only the columns that I have listed in the ColumnName property.

Comment: post more code please maybe we can find for you a linq soultion!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this linq query:

```
var columnsToRemove = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
    .Where(col => !columnInfos.Any(ci => ci.ColumnName == col.ColumnName))
    .ToList();

foreach(DataColumn col in columnsToRemove)
    table.Columns.Remove(col);
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to skin this one - here is an option:

```
List<DataColumn> columnsToRemove = new List<DataColumn>();
foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
{
    if (list.Any(ci => ci.ColumnName == dc.ColumnName))
    {
        continue;
    }

    columnsToRemove.Add(dc);
}

foreach (DataColumn dc in columnsToRemove)
{
    dt.Columns.Remove(dc);
}
```

Comment: or `list.Any(ci => ci.ColumnName == dc.ColumnName)`.

Comment: Switched to use the cleaner Any style and left Neo the points while you were commenting, Eren.

Comment: I believe I have to count from bottom to top because as soon as I remove one item, the foreach gives me an error